# Gps map is working in iphone but not working in ipad?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, ipad, gps

I am developing universal app. Here i am developing gps map concept it is working fine in iphone but not working in iPad. My requirements is i am getting current location by using GPS & i gave one destination place, i have one marker line  from my current location to my destination places (ex:banglore(current location) to Mumbai (destination location)).

This is working in iphone properly but in iPad is not working  it is showing only google map. I need to implement my requirements to iPad also     this is my code base.

Could you please help me to resolve this issues.

```
- (NSString *)stringWithDistance:(double)distance {
    NSLog(@"%f",distance);

    NSString *format;
    if (distance < METERS_CUTOFF) {
        format = @"%@ metres";
    } else {
        format = @"%@ km";
        distance = distance / 1000;
    }


    return [NSString stringWithFormat:format, [self stringWithDouble:distance]];
}
// Return a string of the number to one decimal place and with commas & periods based on the locale.
- (NSString *)stringWithDouble:(double)value {
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    return [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    NSLog(@"%@",school11);
    NSLog(@"lat%@",lat);
    NSLog(@"%@device",deviceType);
    if (!isiPhone5)
    {

       // self.footer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 448, 320, 32);


    }



    NSLog(@"Current identifier: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!isiPhone5)
    {

      //  self.footer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 448, 320, 32);


    }


    [self currentlocation];

}
-(void)currentlocation{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    if ([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {


        mapView = [[[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
                    CGRectMake(0, 50, 768, 1000)] autorelease];

        [self.view addSubview:mapView];


    }
    else{
        if (!isiPhone5)
        {
            mapView = [[[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
                        CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 450)] autorelease];

            [self.view addSubview:mapView];
        }
        else{
            mapView = [[[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
                        CGRectMake(0, 50, 320,  800)] autorelease];

            [self.view addSubview:mapView];
        }
    }





    CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:13.2339538 longitude:80.3323613];

    CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:28.889816 longitude:77.3418147];

    CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
    NSLog(@"%f Meters",distance);
    NSLog(@"%@",    [self stringWithDistance:distance]);


}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
    // CLLocati
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {

        Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
        home.name = @"Vivero International Pre-School";
       // home.description = @"Coyaji Rd, Nilanjali Society, Kalyani Nagar Pune,Maharashtra 411006 India";
        CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
        center=[self getLocationFromAddressString:@"madurai"];
        latFrom=&center.latitude;
        lonFrom=&center.longitude;

        double latt = [lat floatValue];
        double lann = [lon floatValue];
        home.latitude=latt;
        home.longitude=lann;
        CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:home.latitude longitude:home.longitude];



        Place* office = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
        office.name = @"Office";
        office.description = @"current";
        office.latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        office.longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        [mapView showRouteFrom:home to:office];

        CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:office.latitude longitude:office.longitude];

        CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
        NSLog(@"%f Meters",distance);
        NSLog(@"%@",    [self stringWithDistance:distance]);


    }
    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString: (NSString*) addressStr {
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSLog(@"%@",req);
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude=latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    NSLog(@"View Controller get Location Logitute : %f",center.latitude);
    NSLog(@"View Controller get Location Latitute : %f",center.longitude);
    return center;

}
```

Debuging in iphone means it is working properly but in ipad below method is not calling

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {

        Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
        home.name = @"Vivero International Pre-School";

        CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
        center=[self getLocationFromAddressString:@"madurai"];
        latFrom=&center.latitude;
        lonFrom=&center.longitude;

        double latt = [lat floatValue];
        double lann = [lon floatValue];
        home.latitude=latt;
        home.longitude=lann;
        CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:home.latitude longitude:home.longitude];



        Place* office = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
        office.name = @"Office";
        office.description = @"current";
        office.latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        office.longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        [mapView showRouteFrom:home to:office];

        CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:office.latitude longitude:office.longitude];

        CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
        NSLog(@"%f Meters",distance);
        NSLog(@"%@",    [self stringWithDistance:distance]);


    }
    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Finally i am getting this error message in iPad:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]
```

Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: iphone & ipad os versions ?

Comment: @srinivas n Ipad is ios 8.2 and iphone is ios 7.1.

Comment: The above code is not working in ios 8 . Google it for get the location in ios 8 , because stack over flow posting is there check once

Comment: can you please send me that link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134641/how-to-get-current-location-lat-long-in-ios-8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717547/ios-8-map-kit-obj-c-cannot-get-users-location

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 8 you have to use following code.

```
if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
        {
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }

    }


    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And use key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in info.plist and give it description.