# How to get the current location in iOS using google map api.?

Tags: ios

> i am getting current attitude and longitude of device and print it with nslog but now how will update these latttitude and longitude on map accordingly. here is my code please look at this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                        longitude:151.2086
                                                             zoom:12];

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];



mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
self.view = mapView_;
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;

[self startStandardUpdates];

  }



           - (void)startStandardUpdates
        {
// Create the location manager if this object does not
// already have one.

NSLog(@"startupdatelocation");
if (nil == _locationManager)
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

// Set a movement threshold for new events.
_locationManager.distanceFilter = 10; // meters

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }



         - (void)startSignificantChangeUpdates
        {
// Create the location manager if this object does not
// already have one.
if (nil == _locationManager)
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

_locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
       }

      - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
// If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power.
CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
NSLog(@"location %@", location);
NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
    // If the event is recent, do something with it.
    NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude  %+.6f\n",location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);



        }
      }
```

> i am printing current latitude and longitude now how will i show this location on map also please help me in this situation.

Comment: the reason you added the static coordinates **cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                        longitude:151.2086**

Comment: ok sir but when i remove this line of code nothing is appear on view

Comment: i already import corelocation framework but its not working

Comment: 100 % is  not work , the reason in **GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition**  line before you need to fetch your current location and need to display on that position after that it will work

Comment: ok sir, so i need to write code in viewdidload method for get current location.?

Comment: sir please suggest me with some part of code

Answer (score 0):

Current device location should be requested from the iOS - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

than you could show the marker with device location on the map

Comment: should i add key value in plist for this "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities"?

Comment: @sandeeptomar NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription are needed keys. Read more for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134641/how-to-get-current-location-lat-long-in-ios-8